# If each core in my CPU can process one thread at a time, how does using 16 or more threads by so much

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on some programs in Java and am just getting into real multithreading. I was playing with the thread counts and realized that using 20 threads was faster than 8 threads which is how many physical + virtual cores I have.

Why is using 20 threads faster than using 8 if each core in my processor can process only one thread at a time?

Comment: What task are you doing? It is somewhat unlikely that all your threads are working all the time. If some task is IO bound, for example, the CPU can get on and do something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the original reason for multiprocessing and multithreading to be invented had nothing to do with multiple cores. at the time, there was a single core. However, a program is composed by a mix of I/O operations and computation. when a single threaded program initiates an I/O operation, it blocks for a (relatively) large amount of time, and in that time the CPU is idle. But if a second thread is available, and that thread is not blocked on an I/O operation, such thread can be scheduled and make use of the CPU.

To summarize: multithreading helps overlapping I/O of a thread with computation of other threads, hence maximizing the CPU utilization (whether there is one or more)